# NameServer vs DNS A-record

Tags: nameserver, a-record

I have a domain nomadapp.in which is registered at GoDaddy.

For temp hosting i was using Dreamhost and had changed the NameServer in Godaddy to the ones of DreamHost.

Now i want to do the Following

Point

> http://nomadapp.in --> AWS EC2
>
> http://blog.nomadapp.in --> Dreamhost
> where by blog is hosted
>
> http://stats.nomadapp.in --> Dreamhost where
> by stats tracker is hosted

right now in Dreamhost DNS this is what shows up

[image]

Comment: The most common source of confusion with DNS is the difference between the *registrar* and the *DNS provider* since usually the same company provides both services.  In your case, you changed the *DNS provider* from GoDaddy to DreamHost when you pointed the name servers at DreamHost.  All other DNS changes are done at the DNS provider.  The only thing you can change at the registrar is who your DNS provider is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the ip here:

http://ping.eu/nslookup/

So currently the Domain nomadapp.in is mapping to the IP 64.90.45.47. ( Dreamhost Server )

If you want blog.nomadapp.in you have to map this domain via A Record to the IP 64.90.45.47
And stats.nomadapp.in to the IP 64.90.45.47 too.
( I dont know the DNS Management from Dreamhost )

The Domain nomadapp.in you have to map to the AWS EC2 via A Record or CNAME.

You can change the DNS Records where you Domain ist registered.
It seems that you registred the Domain via Dreamhost.
See here the DNS docu from Dreamhost -> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/DNS

**Please notice that it can take up to 48 hours untill the DNS Nameserver is updated.**

Comment: but the a record in the dreamhost is pointing to someother ip. updated my question

Comment: Point the first IP to AWS EC2.
Point blog to the IP of the server where your blog is hosted.
The same thing with stats.

And no it will not slow down your site :)

Comment: glad i could help you. If you`re statisfied i would appreciate it if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is setup an [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) for each service that points to the relevant IP address.

You should probably also familiarise your self with the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [how DNS works](http://dyn.com/blog/dns-why-its-important-how-it-works/).

Comment: should i do that in Godaddy since its hosted there?

Comment: You should do it where your DNS is managed.

Comment: will forwarding DNS from Godaddy to Dreamhost and then setting the a record in Dreamhost to AWS slow the ping time?